# jQuery - selecting input inside td (in same row)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML structure:

```
<tr>
<td class="edit"><input type="checkbox" class="editbox" /></td>
<td class="content"><input type="text" class="contentbox" size="40" disabled="disabled"/></td>
<td class="delete"><input type="checkbox" class="deletebox" /></td>
</tr>
```

What I want? 
When user clicks on input.editbox:

- input.contentbox became editable
- input.deletebox became unchecked (if
  was checked before)

When user click on input.deletebox:

- input.contentbox became disabled
- input.editbox became unchecked (if
  was checked before)

I did this for that structure:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="editbox"/>
<input type="text" class="contentbox" size="40" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="deletebox"/>
```

by using .next() and .prev()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form input.editbox[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).next().removeAttr("disabled");
                $(this).next().next().attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#form input.deletebox[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).prev().attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(this).prev().prev().attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But now can't convert jQuery code for new structure. Any help and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `parent().find(selector)`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form input.editbox[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.contentbox').removeAttr("disabled");
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.deletebox').attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.contentbox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#form input.deletebox[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.contentbox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.editbox').attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In my opinion its better solution than next. This one is much more independent on changes in your html structure. You can rearrange checkboxes in td's and code will still works property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).closest('tr')` with `.find()` instead of using `.next()` or `.prev()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form input.editbox[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
             var $tr =  $(this).closest('tr');
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $tr.find('.contentbox').removeAttr("disabled");
                $tr.find('.deletebox').attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $tr.find('.contentbox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#form input.deletebox[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            var $tr =  $(this).closest('tr');
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $tr.find('.editbox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $tr.find('.contentbox').attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```